# I can no longer get token from facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

This code usually works

```
-(NSString *) strOauthToken
{
    ACAccountCredential *fbCredential = [self.acAcount credential];
    return [fbCredential oauthToken];
}
```

My program would automatically post users review or bookmark to facebook. I need facebook SDK rather than just social framework. So I took ACAccountCredential from social framework and fed the token to facebook IOS SDK.

It used to work fine. It works fine in simulator an all other phone except mine.

Now it always return nil. I've seen

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ACAccount/credential

That says:

> This property is required and must be set before the account is saved.
>   For privacy reasons, this property is inaccessible after the account
>   is saved.

What does it mean that this property is required? What does it mean by the property must be set. I never set this property. Somehow it already contains value. Also when does the account "is saved"

Also why it doesn't work?

It works on most phone and simulator. It doesn't work on my iPhone 5s.

Answer (score 1):

I think we are now using

```
NSString *accessToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken;
```

Can you try it out and let me know if it is working?

Comment: That's the problem. I login using ACAccount framework and I want to use that token for FBSession from Facebook SDK.